# How to create a bar plot for this In R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hi I want a to plot the following dataset:-

| state_ut | year | primary_mean | upper_primary_mean | secondary_mean | hrsecondary_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All India | 2013 | 97.50 | 97.73 | 98.17 | 98.40 |
| All India | 2014 | 97.95 | 98.27 | 98.55 | 98.98 |
| All India | 2015 | 98.27 | 98.57 | 98.89 | 99.02 |

As shown in the image below:-

rough sketch of plot i want

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you show us what you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the mean of each column using `apply` then plot using `barplot`:

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "state_ut   year    primary_mean    upper_primary_mean  secondary_mean  hrsecondary_mean
All_India   2013    97.50   97.73   98.17   98.40
All_India   2014    97.95   98.27   98.55   98.98
All_India   2015    98.27   98.57   98.89   99.02", header = TRUE)

plotdata <- apply(df[-c(1:2)], 2, mean)
```

Plot (base R)

```
xx <- barplot(plotdata, ylim = c(0, 100), # set plot. "xx" will store the positions for the x axis
              axes = FALSE, xaxt = "n", # remove axes with ugly names
              col = 1:4) # set colors
mtext(c("Primary Mean", "Upper Primary Mean", # better x-axis
        "Secondary Mean", "Hrs Secondary Mean"),
      side = 1, at = xx, padj = 2)
axis(2) # y axis
```

[image]